# Best performing method iterating and filtering a collection

Tags: java, performance, optimization, set

What will be the best data structure for the following scenario. 
I have a collection of data and want filter out some data from the collection and put in another collection. Here is my code-

```
final Set<DoubleMatrix1D> l_requiredstaticjumppoints = p_static.stream()
  .filter( i -> this.staticjumppointfilter( p_currentposition.getQuick( 0 ), 
  p_targetposition.getQuick( 0 ), p_currentposition.getQuick( 1 ),
  p_targetposition.getQuick( 1 ), i.getQuick( 0 ), i.getQuick( 1 ), p_objects, 
  l_checkdirection ) )
  .collect( Collectors.toSet() );
```

Here, `l_requiredstaticjumppoints` is a set and `staticjumppointfilter()` is the function which doing the filtering job.

Comment: What is the input and expected output? What are those other variables?

Comment: input is a set of points of grid cell, conditions are the start range and end range and output is a set of points that fall in the given range. First four variables are the ranges, p_objects is full grid matrix and l_checkdirection is the direction of movement(not so important)